# Pylint not recognizing packages installed in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm running a Python project in a Docker container, and I'm using Pylint for linting. However, Pylint doesn't seem to recognize packages that are installed in my Docker container. I know the packages are installed, because I can import them and use them without any issues. But when I run Pylint, I get import errors for those packages.

I'm using VS Code as my editor, and I have the Python extension installed. I've set the Python interpreter in my VS Code workspace to point to the Python executable inside the Docker container, but that doesn't seem to help.
Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image, based on Debian
FROM python:3.9.12 

# set work directory
WORKDIR /home/culturecrawler

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONPATH=/home/culturecrawler

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    llvm-11 \
    libpq-dev \
    build-essential \
    libldap2-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nano

# # install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install pyldap
RUN pip install django-auth-ldap
# to get of the errors in 
RUN pip install Flask==2.0.3 \
    && pip install Werkzeug==2.0.3 

# copy project
COPY . .


# Set default command to launch an interactive shell
RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

And here's the relevant part of my VS Code settings:

```
  // // Python
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    }
  },
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
  "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint",
  "python.formatting.provider": "none",
  "isort.args": ["--profile", "black"],
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--max-line-length=79",
    "--disable=missing-module-docstring,too-few-public-methods"
],
```

How can I get Pylint to recognize the packages installed in my Docker container?

Comment: Will it work if you use shortcuts `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Attach to Running Container` then choose the docker interpreter after installing the [Dev Container extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers)

Answer (score 0):

Use shortcuts `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Attach to Running Container` then choose the docker interpreter after installing the [Dev Container extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers)